# Split list by multiple separators

Tags: python, list

If I have a sentense like that:

```
text = "The sun shine brightly, but is very cold today!"
```

I can use the split:

```
newArray = text.split(" ")
print (newArray)
```

End the result, will be:

```
['The', 'sun', 'shine', 'brightly,', 'but', 'is', 'very', 'cold', 'today!']
```

But, If I need to separate not just only with "Space" but for example "Space", "comma" and "Enter".

How can I do that?

To be more clear, here is my Code example:

```
import io
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import re

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()
    if text:
        return text


text = extract_text_from_pdf('file.pdf')
newArray = text.split(" ")
print (newArray)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in order to split by multiple criteria:

```
text = "The sun shine brightly, but is very cold today!"
```

Say you want to split by spaces and commas:

```
import re
re.split( r'\s+|,\s*', text)
# ['The', 'sun', 'shine', 'brightly', 'but', 'is', 'very', 'cold', 'today!']
```

Comment: Beat me to it,,

Comment: You should really use a raw string for your regex `r'\s+|,\s*'`otherwise weird things might happen.

Comment: Or the other way around, using `re.find`

Comment: Tks...Can I Put here my code to people see, why I asked that?

Comment: If you where to do so, you can always update the question and add the code you've tried or some more details @DaviAmaral

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would probably be to normalize your data, and replace all the "comma" and "enter"s with space, then split as you did before or use `split()` from `re` with `\s` meta.

Comment: Man, I am feeling so stupid now! Perfect! So easy, and I did not think that!

Answer (score 2):

## The str.split() method splits on whitespace and convert into array:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The sun shine brightly, but is very cold today!"
>>> re.findall( r'\s+|,\s*', s)
['The', 'sun', 'shine', 'brightly', 'but', 'is', 'very', 'cold', 'today!']
```

hope you guys use it.

Comment: I like the approach with `re.findall`, but that does that have to do with the sentence above? Probably missing something like "Instead, you could try ..."